# Malware and Antivirus scanner for web servers (free alternative to ISPProtect)

Tags: linux, php, antivirus, malware, centos-7

In short what ispprotect does:

> "ISPProtect is a Malware and Antivirus scanner for web servers. It contains a signature based scan engine and a heuristic scan engine to detect Malware in websites, CMS- and shop systems like WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, Magentocommerce etc. A third scan level in ISPProtect detects outdated installations of e. g. WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, … and shows their location on the web server. ISPProtect is developed by the ISPConfig developer team. ISPConfig is a widely used OpenSource Webhosting Control Panel." - [ISPProtect, ISPProtect Malware Scanner](https://ispprotect.com/)

My only dislike is that it costs a lot. A whole lot.

Does anybody know of a free(FOSS) alternatives to this software?

Answer (score 1):

Try ClamAV... ISPProtect uses ClamAV for its scans and it's free. But IMHO ISPProtect is the best Malware-Webserver Scanner out there. I struggled a lot with malware on one of my servers. With ispprotect I managed to locate all the malware and to close all the backdoors.

And concerning the price: +- 100€ per year is nothing compared to the price/hour you spend on battling with malware by yourself...

I spent hours and hours to find a good scanner... I am using the scanner for 3 months now and since then I had no more malware on my server... I can absolutely recommend it.